# How to transmit password during registration (PHP & SQL)

Tags: php, sql, authentication, passwords, registration

I know the standard answer for anyone trying to implement user authentication is to use a ready built and tested library, but I've always loved reinventing the wheel.

I've create a user authentication and session data system in PHP, using the challenge-response technique to login. All private pages require a function at the beginning which verifies the session checking for session timeout, ip, browser and a 256bit token key. After verifying the session, it resets the timeout and generates a new token key.

The biggest weak point I can see at the moment however is the **user registration**. I haven't written it yet, but it looks like I'm going to have to transmit from the client to the server either the password in plaintext, or a hashed version. Either way, if the packet is captured the snoop has all they need to login.

Is there an easy way to somehow encrypt it client side and decrypt server side? Or Perhaps send it in chunks with delays and dummy packets.

Also, if there are any other issues I may have missed please let me know.

- Log in asks for a challenge salt, and client hashes password before sending it
       hash(hash(password) . salt).
- To persist a session, client must have up to date token key and identical browser & IP to those that created the session.
- Naturally, all user inputs & ajax responses are checked before querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really one correct answer:
Use HTTPS. SSL over HTTP is the only solution that will completely make this secured.

You can't do any javascript check here because the salt will be exposed. Which is not the correct approach.

Comment: SSL is a pain because the intention is to implement this into a CMS; so the code would be on a client's server, so they wont have a static IP and a certificate. I guess I could route registration through my server.

Comment: @Oliver then their site is never going to be that secure anyway, since without HTTPS, each time people sign in their credentials will be sent over the wire unencrypted, and they'll be sending their authenticated session IDs in cookies unencrypted with each request to the server. So why make a big deal about registration?

Comment: Any encryption key used by javascript can be exposed by viewing the source I guess.

Comment: @Mark authenticated sessions are also tied with a changing token key, so you would need to catch the session ID and token and make a request before the real user does anything, as well as know the real user's IP and browser. And when the real user tries to do something after the sesion is hijjacked, they destroy the session.

Comment: @Oliver Great, frequent session regeneration helps. By 'token key' I guess you mean the session ID, or do you mean a CSRF token? The lack of HTTPS during sign in is still a problem. Whatever you do for registration, be sure to do it for that as well, right?

Comment: @Oliver: You don't need a static IP for SSL. All you need is a webserver and a domain. The SSL certificate certifies the DOMAIN NAME you're connecting to isn't lying. The IP could change on every request, but as long as the cert's name and the address in the URL match up, everything's fine.

Comment: @Mark Should have mentioned, I'm not using php sessions I'm using my own system completely. Sessions have a simple incrementing ID, and then a token bound to it. A token is simply made by hash('sha256', mt_rand()). During sign in, the client sends the username and server responds with a salt (made same as a token). Client then sends hash( hash(password) . salt ), so capturing the salt wont help much. As far as I can see, sign in is pretty secure.

Comment: @Marc B: The only problem is it generates warning messages in most browsers. Chrome tries to convince me my webmail is going to kill me. But if this is for registration only, its not the end of the word.

Comment: @Oliver: What warnings? There's plenty of sites with multiple IPs and a single ssl cert without any warnings (e.g. amazon.com)

Comment: @Marc B: Hmm. I was under the impression that in order to get a verified SSL certificate, you needed a static IP that the verification company can bind it to. And if you using a certificate that isn't verified by someone (e.g. Verisign), then the browser will give warnings.

Comment: @Oliver: The self-signed cert warning has nothing to do with IP addresses. It just means that browsers don't recognize "Acme Certs-R-Us" as a valid CA. To get an SSL cert issued, you just have to certify that the domain you're getting it issued for is actually your domain. but nowhere in the cert application process does it say that "example.com" is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Marc B: OK, thanks for clearing that up. But can you use SSL on a shared web server? I have a cheap shared web host, and looking around in their support section suggests that you wont be able to SSL until you pay for a signed cert. and static IP.

Comment: Static v.s. dynamic IPs don't matter. But sharing a single IP across multiple SSL domains is problematic. Some webservers (and webhosts) don't support it at all. TLS alleviates the problem (1 IP = multiple ssl domains), but on old-school SSL-only hosts, the rule is 1 IP = 1 SSL domain only.

Comment: So back to the original question. There is no practical way to securely send a password during registration other than via SSL. Is there anything that can be done to at least make it harder to capture?

Comment: Any encryption used would require either a static key which could be easily exposed, or a dynamic key that could be exposed by capturing packets. This means the password, or hash could be discovered. Is there any benefit to encrypting the password if both the key and the method can be easily discovered?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to somehow encrypt it client side and decrypt server side?

How about using HTTPS?